# print preg_place unexpected error

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
print "<a href='".preg_replace($replace, '-', $name."-pid-".$id.".html'>";
```

and receive the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\s.php on line 98
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't close the round bracket.

```
print "<a href='".preg_replace($replace, '-', $name)."-pid-".$id.".html'>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't close the parentheses. Try this:

```
print "<a href='".preg_replace($replace, '-', $name."-pid-".$id.".html'>");
```